# Seeing Error Message "This Browser is incapable of supporting the Tableau JavaScript API" in Internet Explorer 8

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer-8, tableau-api

I am new to Tableau and to teach myself in order to get up to speed, I have been following the online tutorials plus trying the code.

With a work colleague, who created a report and published it to Tableau Public, I created a small JavaScript file and web page, which contained the following code to run the report in the page:

```
window.onload = function(){
    var vizDiv = document.getElementById('viz');
    var vizURL = "http://public.tableausoftware.com/views/DashboardDraft1_1/7DayKPI1Ids";
    var options = {
        width: '1200px',
        height: '800px',
        hideToolbar: true,
        hideTabs: true
    };
    viz = new tableauSoftware.Viz(vizDiv, vizURL, options);
};
```

The script is not working in IE 8,and when I view the problem using Developer Tools in the browser, it says "This browser is incapable of supporting the Tableau JavaScript API". I note in the documentation that it says to disable IE Compatibility Mode, but this script is not being run from IIS, but simply from my desktop (the compatibility icon is not visible in the browser) - I am not sure if this makes a difference.

Can someone please advise me what the issue exactly is?

Many thanks

Comment: Well, as I said in the note their documentation says it can! All I am looking for whether anyone else has suffered the same problem, whether they had a work around - not comments!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone hitting this problem and need to work with older IE Browsers - ensure that IE Compatibility Mode is "TURNED OFF", and when using Developer Tools in IE ensure Document Mode is IE 8 Standard. Then everything will work!

Comment: You can force IE not to use Compatibility Mode by adding a header tag to IIS 'X-UA-Compatible' set it equal to 'IE=Edge' and this will force IE to always use it latest rendering engine.